# why a is_sum_tree check is not valid on the tree which was convert to sum tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree

I was getting extremly confused with the algorithm of converting a binary tree to sum_tree.

So, the below tree is a valid sum tree. In which root node is equivalent to the sum of all the nodes in left subtree and right subtree.
http://www.techcrashcourse.com/2016/06/program-to-check-binary-tree-is-sum-tree.html

```
/*
This function returns below tree
            82
           / \
         35   6
        / \    \
       15  5    6
      / \
     7  8
*/
```

Now, the method to convert a binary tree to sum tree is in this link - http://algorithms.tutorialhorizon.com/convert-binary-tree-to-its-sum-tree/ . The resulted tree doesn't satisfy the logic of is_sumtree method.

I understood both the algorithm, but if the resulted tree doesn't satisfy is_sumtree method then what is the use of it?

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand the concept. Let's see the definition:

> Sum tree of a binary tree, is a tree where each node in the con­verted
>   tree will con­tains the sum of the left and right sub trees in the
>   orig­i­nal tree.

This means that a node in a sum tree will be equal with the corresponding node's descendants' sum from the original tree. Your understanding that the nodes of a sum tree will be equal to the sum of their descendants in the sum tree is a misinterpretation. Take a look at any node of the original tree and sum the descendants. Take a look at the corresponding node in the sum tree. You will see an exact match.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard term as *sum tree*. The two links use different policy for leaves to build sum tree. And both are correct as what they want to mean. Building a sum- tree is generally a sub-problem or structural manipulation of given tree to solve bigger problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a definition question only. According to definition of sum tree of a binary tree, it **may be not the sum tree itself**. Maybe you want to choose another definition: for example, sum tree of a binary tree is a **sum tree** with the same structure and values in leaves. Of course, such definition requires another conversion algorithm.